# How to assign colors according to median value in box plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have an issue with a color palette of my box plot. I want that the colors get assigned according to median values. The higher is the median value, the darker is a color. I selected the palette `YlGnBu`. However, colors are assigned just as a gradient - darker colors are on the right, while lighter colors are on the left:

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

norm = plt.Normalize(df["total_bill"].values.min(), df["total_bill"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.YlGnBu(norm(df["total_bill"]))
flierprops = dict(markerfacecolor='0.75', markersize=5,linestyle='none')

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=df, 
                 palette=colors, 
                 flierprops=flierprops) # hue="smoker", 
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x,p: str(x)+":00"))
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x,p: locale.format('%d', x, 1)))
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#d3d3d3', linewidth=1.0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#d3d3d3', linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your setting up your colormap based on the whole range of `total_bill` values in your dataframe. If you want the colormap to reflect the median values per day of the week, you have to set up using those median values.

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

median_vals = df.groupby('day')['total_bill'].median()
norm = plt.Normalize(median_vals.min(), median_vals.max())
colors = plt.cm.YlGnBu(norm(median_vals))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=df, palette=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]